# Multiple colored balls in box

Tags: combinatorics

I have a box full with $n$ balls of different color but only one of each color e.g. 1 red, 1 green, 1 yellow, 1 blue etc.

We pull out balls without laying them back.

Here if we want to compute all possibilities (order doesn't matter) after $k$ pulls, the answer is $\binom{n}{k}$. This is clear.

**But how does the answer change if we allow multiple balls of one color, e.g. the box is filled with 2 red 3 green 1 yellow and 4 blue balls? How many possibilities are now possible?**

Comment: If the balls are uniquely labeled, still $\binom{n}{k}$ and if we are wishing to use such an analysis to predict things using probability it is incredibly helpful to pretend that the balls are in fact labeled so as to allow us to use counting techniques to calculate probabilities... even if this were not actually true.  If you do wish to treat two outcomes as "the same" for counting (*despite the warnings that this makes the outcomes no longer equiprobable for probability purposes*) then you can treat this by some mix of stars-and-bars and inclusion-exclusion if you insist.

Comment: The easiest though to explain would be by generating functions... looking at the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $\underbrace{(1+x+x^2)}_{\text{two red balls}}(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x)\underbrace{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)}_{\text{four blue balls}}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm sorry still in high school, I don't understand. Is there a way to solve this "easily" with the six well known cases of permutation, variation and combination?

Comment: No.  You need additional tools and understanding, unless you insist on using only the basics at which point you would need to break into cases... at which point you can quickly and easily devolve into "case hell" where there are far too many cases to feasibly track, which is why I suggested the generating functions approach if all you cared about was getting the answer and didn't mind using computer help with what is essentially disguised brute force.  Even with stars-and-bars and inclusion-exclusion, the answer to the general problem is far too ugly to take the time to write out.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay interesting, I guess it's a "very easy question" but the answer is way harder than expected.

Comment: With three colors, there being $A$ available of the first color, $B$ of the second, and $C$ of the third, having $N=A+B+C$ in total, and wishing to choose $k$ where order doesn't matter and all balls indistinguishable except by color... there would be $\binom{k+2}{2}-\binom{k-A+1}{2}-\binom{k-B+1}{2}-\binom{k-C+1}{2}+\binom{k-A-B}{2}+\binom{k-A-C}{2}+\binom{k-B-C}{2}-\binom{k-A-B-C-1}{2}$.  Expanding out to a fourth color doubles the number of terms in the expansion, and expanding out to an arbitrary number of colors involves creative uses of subset notation within indices of summations.

Comment: Of course, certain special cases can have easy simplifications... such as when we have more balls of each color individually than what we are taking out... at which point this is a simple stars-and-bars problem where we have $\binom{k+c-1}{c-1}$ outcomes where $k$ is the number of balls and $c$ is the number of colors available... in your problem for instance if we take out two balls, there would be $\binom{2+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{5}{3}=10$ but we see we couldn't have taken out two yellow so we correct the count by subtracting $1$ giving $9$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is certainly a "easy" way to to this problem
You would first add up all the balls,
In this case 2+3+1+4=10

Then you would take the factorial of the number which is 10!

after this the process is quite simple
just divide your sum factorial by the factorial of different numbers

$\frac{(10!)}{2!3!1!4!}$
Which would give your required answer
=12600

Now this would give you the total combinations
But if you want to explore more and get into more detail about how to derive the formula you have to apply a PIE (principle of inclusion exclusion).
Hope this clears it.

PS- This concepts only applies if the balls are not distinct
If the balls are distinct you would use the standard way.

Comment: But that would only be the case if I decide to pull every ball from the box right? (So n=k). If k<n this doesn't work, right?

Comment: For that you have to make cases by using systematic counting as well as stars and bars concepts.Typically such big number of cases do not usually come in this question if k<n. But lets say for the sake of it that k=2 then you would have to form the equation x+y+z=2 and then make cases for all the non negative integral solutions.

Comment: Such is the beauty of combinatorics as there are no 'easy way' to solve such problems(like just putting it into a formula)